# Behat can't find PhpExecutableFinder

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, composer-php, behat, mink

I get the following error when executing Behat:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Component\Process\PhpExecutableFinder' not found
```

I don't know if its normal, but the `PhpExecutableFinder` is located within my composer.phar after php composer.phar update is called.

```
{
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4",
        "ext-mcrypt": "*",
        "slim/slim": "~2.0",
        "slim/views": "0.1.*",
        "twig/twig": "1.18.*",
        "propel/propel": "~2.0@dev",
        "zeflasher/propel2-geocodable-behavior": "dev-master",

        "behat/behat": "3.0.*@stable",
        "behat/mink": "1.6.*@stable",
        "behat/mink-extension": "@stable",
        "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "@stable",
        "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "@stable",
        "peridot-php/leo": "~1.0"
    },

    "autoload": {
        "classmap": ["website/", "vendor/"]
    }
}
```

Is my current composer.json. Can anybody reproduce it? composer.phar is self-updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
composer require symfony/process
```

That solved the issue. I don't know why its not included in behat.